# Change IsEnabled & IsVisible on Password Confirmation in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin App, I'm trying to use change the `IsVisible` for `Frame` and `IsEnabled` for `Button`, when the Password is Confirmed (Password & Confirm Password should've same text), but it isn't changing anything.

One Irony is that when the App opens up, by default (there isn't any value entered), the `Password.Text == ConfirmPassword.Text` is True.

I want to change it, when the Values of both `Entry` fields are same. Thanks.

**.xml Code**

```
<Entry
    x:Name="Password"
    IsPassword="True"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    MaxLength="8"
    ReturnType="Next" />
                        
<Entry
    x:Name="ConfirmPassword"
    IsPassword="True"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    MaxLength="8"
    ReturnType="Done" />


<Frame x:Name="RedBar" BackgroundColor="#E1444D" IsVisible="true">
    <BoxView />
</Frame>
                
<Frame x:Name="GreenBar" BackgroundColor="#24D27F" IsVisible="false">
    <BoxView />
</Frame>


<Button
    x:Name="PasswordButton"
    IsEnabled="False"
    Text="Submit">
</Button>
```

**.xml.cs Code**

```
public PasswordPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (Password.Text == ConfirmPassword.Text)
    {
        RedBar.IsVisible = false;
        GreenBar.IsVisible = true;
        PasswordButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    else
    {
        RedBar.IsVisible = true;
        GreenBar.IsVisible = false;
        PasswordButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a namespace 'x' which is not defined.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for responding. when I used `Name`, it said, **Property 'Name' wasn't found**... and it didn't return any error for `x:Name`, and I think it's defined on top of the page in .xml page `x:Class="Osma.Mobile.App.Views.PasswordPage"`, am I right ?

Comment: tThe place where the namespace is defined will have xmlns:x="URL"

Comment: your need add one more condition to your if which check !string.IsNullOrWhite(Password)

Comment: initially when u are starting the app in your both entry there is a white space which is same for both password and confirm password and hence the condition which u have written turns to be true

Comment: @jdweng  `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"`, this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Xaml Code**

```
<Entry
    x:Name="Password"
    IsPassword="True"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    MaxLength="8"
    ReturnType="Next" Unfocused="Password_Unfocused" />

        <Entry
    x:Name="ConfirmPassword"
    IsPassword="True"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    MaxLength="8"
    ReturnType="Done" Unfocused="ConfirmPassword_Unfocused"/>


        <Frame x:Name="RedBar" BackgroundColor="#E1444D" IsVisible="true">
            <BoxView />
        </Frame>

        <Frame x:Name="GreenBar" BackgroundColor="#24D27F" IsVisible="false">
            <BoxView />
        </Frame>


        <Button
    x:Name="PasswordButton"
            Clicked="PasswordButton_Clicked"
    IsEnabled="False"
    Text="Submit">
        </Button>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public PasswordPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ValidatePassword();
}

private void Password_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            ValidatePassword();
        }

        private void ConfirmPassword_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            ValidatePassword();
        }

 private void ValidatePassword()
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfirmPassword.Text))
                {
                    if (Password.Text == ConfirmPassword.Text)
                    {
                        RedBar.IsVisible = false;
                        GreenBar.IsVisible = true;
                        PasswordButton.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
    
                    else
                    {
                        RedBar.IsVisible = true;
                        GreenBar.IsVisible = false;
                        PasswordButton.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    RedBar.IsVisible = true;
                    GreenBar.IsVisible = false;
                    PasswordButton.IsEnabled = false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your if condition to this

```
if (Password.Text == ConfirmPassword.Text && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password.Text))
{
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding.. the `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password.Text)` didn't worked, but I used `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password.Text)` and this statement worked.. but, it still isn't changing the value of  `IsEnabled` & `IsVisible`, even if the text of `Password` and `ConfirmPassword` is same

Comment: u need to check for empty and space and u need (!)not sign before that statement

Comment: the other way is Password.Text != " "

Comment: my bad it worked.. but one thing remained to solved, to change the value of `IsEnabled & IsVisible` if the `Password.Text == ConfirmPassword.Text`, which it isn't (Event)

Answer (score 0):

Use following linq :

```
       const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            List<XElement> entries = doc.Descendants("Entry").ToList();

            string name1 = (string)entries[0].Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Name").FirstOrDefault();
            string name2 = (string)entries[1].Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Name").FirstOrDefault();
 
        }
```