# Change TextColor & Use Command on IsEnabled in Button in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using `IsEnabled` on **Button** in Xamarin App and there is 2 things I can't do.

1. Change the `TextColor` when the `IsEnabled = false`, but I can change the `BackgroundColor`.

The solution is to use the Custom Entry and there is great article for that => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry

But it only works with:

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
{
}
```

and the code behind my Page is:

```
public class MyEntry : ContentPage
{
}
```

and also I can't use multiple classes. Is there any way to use the `Entry` with `ContentPage` in **xml.cs** Page?

2. I want to enable the `Command` only when the `IsEnabled = true` e.g. the `ICommand` in **ViewModel** should only works, when the `IsEnabled` value is `true`.

Complete Code Sample => https://stackoverflow.com/a/64808306/14139029

**.xml**

```
<Button
    x:Name="PasswordButton"
    IsEnabled="False"
    TextColor="#4DABFE"
    BackgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
    Text="Submit"
    Command={Binding PasswordButtonCommand}>
</Button>
```

**.xml.cs**

```
if (Password.Text == ConfirmPassword.Text)
{
    PasswordButton.IsEnabled = true;
    PasswordButton.TextColor = Color.FromHex("004B87");
    PasswordButton.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("222222");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As when you set the Button `IsEnabled="False"`,it will use a default style of the button.

If you want to use your custom style and handle the `Command` when `IsEnable` is true.you could define a custom property in your viewmodel,and then trigger your `Command` based on this property.

For example:

```
public class ViewModel
{

    public ICommand PasswordButtonCommand => new Command<Button>(Submit);
    public bool IsEnable { get; set; }

    private void Submit(object obj)
    {

        if (IsEnable)
        {
             //do something you want
        }
    
    }
}
```

then in your Entry `TextChanged` event :

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Password.Text == ConfirmPassword.Text)
        {
            viewModel.IsEnable = true;
            PasswordButton.TextColor = Color.FromHex("004B87");
            PasswordButton.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("222222");
        }
        else
        {
            viewModel.IsEnable = false;
            PasswordButton.TextColor = Color.FromHex("4DABFE");
            PasswordButton.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("FFFFFF");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got error on `viewModel.IsEnable = true;` that `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'viewModel.IsEnable'`.. so, I made the `public bool IsEnable { get; set; }` static, and it worked... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Change the TextColor when the IsEnabled = false, but I can change the BackgroundColor. Why?

Yes, you can change the BackgroundColor but not the TextColor becuase it overrides internally. You will have to create renderer to change the text color.

> 2. When I use Command, the IsEnabled becomes true. The IsEnabled didn't work then. Code for IsEnabled is written in .xml.cs page. Is
>    there any possibility to use Command with IsEnabled?

There is no relation between command and IsEnabled property so it should work.

**Xaml.cs**

```
<Button
    x:Name="PasswordButton"
            Clicked="PasswordButton_Clicked"
    IsEnabled="False" Command="{Binding PasswordButtonCommand}"
    Text="Submit">
        </Button>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        
        public ICommand PasswordButtonCommand => new Command(Submit);

        private void Submit(object obj)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Test");
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```